# Zend Framework 1.12, ContextSwitch or AjaxContext not disabling layout and other problems

Tags: javascript, ajax, zend-framework, ajaxcontext

Environment:
Windows 8
Apache 2.4
ZF 1.12
PHP 5.4
YUI framework for the behind-the-scenes connection to the server

I am trying to carry out a very simple ajax/js combination where the user interacts with:

```
2 of 4 people found this review helpful. Was this review helpful to you? Yes No
```

When the user hits either yes/no the 2 of 4 should be updated through ajax/js. I have the following code in the init() method of my ReviewController (extends Zend_Controller_Action). Mind you, the view script that follows this action (feedbackAction) is /views/scripts/review/feedback.json.phtml

```
 $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
 $ajaxContext->addActionContext('feedback', 'json')
             ->initContext();
```

When feedbackAction is executed an exception jumps out stating that it could not find feedback.phtml. This is telling me that AjaxContext is not, in effect, appending the "json" format. Why is this happening?
I read somewhere that the initContext() should be called inside the action. I tried it...same exception.

Then I tried using ContextSwitch, but it seems that it beats the purpose of having AjaxContext be a subclass of ContextSwitch. The code in the init() in ReviewController was replaced by:

```
    $contextSwitch = $this->_helper->getHelper('contextSwitch');
    $contextSwitch->addActionContext('feedback', 'json')
                ->initContext();
```

This time, inexplicably, the exception does not occur, but instead the following is rendered: the header code (generated by my _header.phtml file called by my layout.phtml file). I don´t understand at all. I had understood (obviously not well) that "addActionContext"+initContext() DISABLED layouts if any was enabled. ¿?

**EDIT**
I figured out that it wasn´t html content form my _header.phtml file but from another .phtml file that was being rendered because of some actions I had added to my actionStack. Once this was taken care of, what was rendered was the following:

```
{"originalModule":"default","originalController":"review","originalAction":"feedback","result":true,"id":1,"helpful_yes":"3","helpful_total":"4"}
```

Which is the variables placed in the $this->view being rendered as json thanks to ContextSwitch helper initiated at the init() method of my ReviewController(). When I say "this was rendred" is because I placed in the address bar the following url: `http://localhost/PlacesforKids/public/review/feedback/format/json/id/1/helpful/1`

which supposedly is the URL being sent by the YUI framework.

I say "supposedly" because in my javascript success function (being called back by the YUI framework when the ajax call is being executed successfully) I do the fowlling: alert(response), to print out the responce I am getting...and it prints out the whole shabang: html tags, headers...etc. I don´t know how that´s possible.

I thought then that I might be misusing the YUI framework, so I tried to change to jquery.js. To do so I copied the contect of [this](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.js) to a file named jquery.js and placed it under my /public/js directory. Here is the ajax call it´s making to the server:

```
$.ajax({
url: sUrl,//that would be   
          //localhost/PlacesforKids/public/review/feedback/format/json/id/$id/helpful/$helpful
type: "GET",
async: false,
success: function(response){
    alert(response);
}
```

});

Here is the HILARIOUS part of all, the action for my ReviewController is NOT being called whatsoever. Instead, the view that was last rendered is re-rendered, meaning it´s re sending the content generated by the view script called by the last action (which belongs to a different controller than ReviewController). I know it´s been re-rendered because in the action that´s the owner of that view script I added this:

```
if($this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax') == 1)
            throw new Exception ("WRONG controller's action being called");
```

But it never throws the exception.

**EDIT I THINK I GOT IT but I need to know how to clean the baseUrl()**
So I opened up the java console on my chrome browser so I could look up the actual http request that my reviewFeedback.js was making through the $.ajax() method. Funny thing, this is what I got:

```
    Request URL:http://localhost/PlacesforKids/public/place/index/id/localhost/PlaceforKids/public/review/feedback/format/json/id/1/helpful/0
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Accept:*/*
Referer:http://localhost/PlacesforKids/public/place/index/id/1
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

WHY in the world is $ajax() APPENDING the url I have as GET to the EXISTING url? It means that whatever url I am trying to generate through my $.ajax() is gettign APPENDED to my "referer". So, I only need to be to CLEAN it and start from zero, for the url I mean... How could I do that in zend framework? Any ideas?

Now if I enter the string in sUrl (localhost/PlaceforKids/public/review/feedback/format/json/id/1/helpful/0) directly onto the address bar in my broswer, it does as it is supposed to do, print out the variables in $this->view that have been set by ReviewController, and send them as json.

```
{"originalModule":"default","originalController":"review","originalAction":"feedback","result":true,"id":1,"helpful_yes":"3","helpful_total":"4"}
```

Same problem I had with YUI framework. I´m going crazy.

I could really use the help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly silly silly me. Here is the reason why $.ajax() was appending the made up url instead of sending a new one.

```
$.ajax({
url: sUrl,//that would be   
          //localhost/PlacesforKids/public/review/feedback/format/json/id/$id/helpful/$helpful
type: "GET",
async: false,
success: function(response){
    alert(response);
}
```

I was writing a GET without a leading "http://", which by default, caused it to append to the existing url.

```
sUrl was localhost/PlacesforKids/public/review/feedback/format/json/id/$id/helpful/$helpful
and should have been http://localhost/PlacesforKids/public...
```

Though it still baffles me that ajaxContext did not stop layout rendering as it should have, making me use switchContext instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the ajax request to asynchronous mode: `async: true`

Comment: I changed the code in $.ajax({...}); to async: true, as you suggested. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax switch in zend 1.1x.x is only for the "special" html context (if memory serves) and you were trying to set it to a json context.